Вопрос по оператору `is`
Почему в примере ниже Foo1 возвращает true, а Foo2 возвращает false?
static bool Foo1<T>(T v) => v is var b;
static bool Foo2<T>(T v) => v is T b;

static void Main(string[] args)
{
   int? i = null;
   bool f1 = Foo1(i);
   bool f2 = Foo2(i);
}


Вы по прошлым вопросам на тему is ещё не со всем разобрались? Я пока их читал, кажется, уже разобрался.

@CrazyElf, ну если разобрались тогда скажите, в примере вопроса переменная b в Foo1 какой тип имеет? А в Foo2 переменная b какой тип имеет? А T это какой тип?

is var паттерн означает "совпадет со всем, даже если это null", поэтому true. И результат равен исходному параметру. Компилятор в релизе даже выбросит эту проверку. А is T не может скастить null до типа T, поэтому false

@Андрей В Foo1 у b нет никакого типа, это просто значение null. А в Foo2 T это видимо int, а b это null, поэтому False.

@CrazyElf, у переменной не может не быть типа. Вы можете чётко сказать какой тип у b и что есть T в функциях Foo1 и Foo2?

T это int?. У b будет автоматом такой же тип, если выполнение дойдет до присвоения b чего либо (потому что в вашем случае компилятор просто выбросит b при компиляции)

Ваш Foo1 является эквивалентом bool Foo1<T> (T v) { return true; } (пример), ну а теперь скажите, какой тип у b в данном случае? Если она будет использоваться где либо, то ее тип будет такой, какой вы задаете через T методу (и да, там также будет возврат return true, ибо вы не делаете каких либо проверок.

Ладно, раз уж вы не можете чётко и однозначно сказать, то тогда скажу я: и в Foo1 и в Foo2 b имеет тип int? а T является int?. Если не согласны то может быть это https://dotnetfiddle.net/uXjJre докажет или посмотрите что показывает отладчик.
Тогда исходя из этого получается что и v is T b и v is var b есть v is int? b и почему они не аналогичны не понятно.

Вам четко и однозначно дали ответ, чего в нем вам не понятно, я лично не знаю. Что не понятного в "Он ничего не проверяет, а просто создаёт временную переменную", что не понятного в "null это не int", что не понятного в "Ваш Foo1 является эквивалентом bool Foo1<T> (T v) { return true; }"...?

@Андрей Ладно, я частично с вами согласен. T - это действительно int?, я проверил. Далее. v у вас null. Как проверить тип объекта в C#? Ну разве что взять от объекта .GetType, но проблема в том, что от null нельзя взять .GetType()! От него ничего нельзя взять, это null, в C# это специальный тип объекта, от которого ничего нельзя вызвать, никакого метода. В общем, тип объекта null никак не может быть int? или любой другой конкретный тип. А вот is var всегда True и он ничего не проверяет. By design просто, так сделано.

Забейте ваш код в https://sharplab.io и сами увидите во что его перепишет компилятор.

@vitidev Кстати, да, очень наглядно и понятно, почему всё так.

Для тех кто не в курсе: int? является типом значения поэтому при вызове GetType он боксится, но боксится не как все остальные типы значений а особым образом, а конкретнее боксится не сам 'int?' а int в случае если .HasValue == true и не боксится ничего если .HasValue == false.

@vitidev, вопрос не в том во что перепишет компилятор а почему он это делает не логично.

@Андрей Логично было бы запретить использовать nullable типы в качестве T, потому что там неоднозначность получается.

А нелогичность возникает из-за того что для ссылочных типов T в is T a это не просто T а NotNullable.
Разное представлении для ссылочных и структурных типов и создаёт эту нелогичность:

Для типов значения
T? a - а может содержать что-то типа T или ничего не содержать (null).
is T a - а содержит что-то типа T,
Для ссылочных типов
T a - а может ссылается на что-то типа T (или унаследованного от T) или ни на что не ссылаться (null),
is T a - а ссылается на что-то имеющее тип T (или унаследованного от T).


Подскажите вот https://sharplab.io показывает что v is T b это (v != null), а если оператор != переопределён в T, то что тогда происходит?

Переопределённый оператор не будет использоваться при сопоставлении шаблона. Это декомпилированный код, в данном контексте != можно читать как is not. У примитивов вы не можете переопределять операторы, компилятор это знает, поэтому использует простое сравнение.

"Шаблон var используется для сопоставления любого выражения, в том числе null и назначения результата новой локальной переменной."
То есть фактически is var всегда будет равен True. Он ничего не проверяет, а просто создаёт временную переменную.
А во втором случае null это не int, поэтому будет False. При сопоставлении x is T, где T - это конкретный тип, случай, когда x - это null, обрабатывается отдельно. null не сопоставляется ни с каким конкретным типом, даже если этот тип Nullable. В случае null такое сопоставление не срабатывает и возвращается False.
